# Flat UI strange black border issue in iphone browser ( Both Safari and Chrome )

Tags: ios, css, google-chrome, safari, flat

I'm using Flat-UI by designmodo for my project. I noticed there is a problem when i viewed pages in iphone. There are strange black borders occurred in item of navigation and in checkboxes. And it happen in both Safari and Chrome. The problem was also occurred when i viewed Flat-UI official demo pages. Is there any way to fix this problem ?

Screenshot in safari : http://postimg.org/image/4sjacbnsv/

Screenshot in Chrome : http://postimg.org/image/u6870c7ul/

Comment: Can you post the code? Can't solve what I don't see. http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: I found this problem in Flat-UI demo pages. You can try : http://designmodo.github.io/Flat-UI/ . Thank you !